# I have a button which opens windows file explorer to browse a file. how can i do that with cypress?

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress, cypress-file-upload

below is my html:

```
<button ng-if="!isIE()" id="UploadedFileBtn" data-ng-click="SelectFile()" title="Browse" 
text="Browse" style="padding-bottom :5px" class="ng-scope">
        <mosaic-icon name="upload" width="20" height="20" class="">
          <svg class="icon" width="20" height="20"><use xlink:href="#mosaic_icon_upload"> 
          </use></svg> 
        </mosaic-icon>
</button>
```

this button does not have type="file" or not a browse button. its just a button which opens a file explorer and i need to select a file from it.

below my js file code:

```
const imgfile = 'Needlers76950.pdf';
cy.get("#UploadedFileBtn > mosaic-icon > .icon").click().attachFile(imgfile);
```

have done all the prerequisite for cypress file upload plugins.

Comment: Did you try targetting the ```use``` element? ```cy.get("#UploadedFileBtn > mosaic-icon > .icon > use")```

Comment: @cypher_null no, it still does not open the file explorer.